# Having issue in Swing combo box

Tags: java, swing

I have a text box and one combo box, in combo box I store list of commands. 
When I type command in text box with initial some letter with related command, it shows the matching command in combo box, but it does not show in top of the combo box. 
It shows in the middle, last where the command exist in combo box. 
So please suggest me a sample code. When I type command it should show selected command in combo box top.

Comment: for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Also consider a more descriptive title. I don't think there's a single questioner here that doesn't have an issue to ask about. =)

Comment: don't understand what you mean by _show matching command in combo box_ vs. _not show in top of combo box_ ...

Comment: Hi Kleopatra, for example I have a one combo box, in this i have store list of countries and have one text box. When i enter text in text box(like in or any other text) then select related matched word with "in" in combo box and it will display at top after scroll. But in my case after select word with in combo box it not scroll and not come at top. So how to scroll dynamically when selected item shown at top.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for an editable `JComboBox` with auto-completion feature. [This article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html) discusses how this can be achieved using some of the popular Swing 3th party libraries + explains more or less how auto-completion works

Comment: +1 guessing auto-complete is as good as anything else (as long as the OP doesn't clarify :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for yourComboBox.setSelectedIndex(int), if you want to show that related command in JComboBox (when its not expanded).